# Tkinter - Seleccionar y copiar Label

Tags: python, tkinter, select, label

Soy nuevo en esto de programar y después de hacer un par de cursos me decidí a intentar hacer mi primera app.
La idea es hacer una especie de bloc de notas pero con calculadora incorporada (ej: OpalCalc) y me surgió el primer problema:
Ya puedo ingresar cuentas en la primer linea de un Text y que salga en una Label el resultado, pero no puedo seleccionar ese resultado en el label con el mouse para poder copiarlo. Cómo le hago?

Espero se entienda,
Saludos y gracias!

Comment: Te recomiendo utilizar un entry con state="readonly" en lugar de un label. El entry en modo readonly no puede escribirse pero si se puede seleccionar su contenido y copiarlo.

Comment: Cuando digo que no puede escribirse me refiero a que el usuario es el que no puede hacerlo. Aun puedes escribir contenido en el Entry programaticamente.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: El problema de poner un entry con read only en lugar de un label es que el resultado no se muestra en el entry con readonly. Alguna solucion? Muchas gracias por la respuesta y perdon por la tardanza, re colgue